# unable to locate the package gzlib

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling

I use Ubuntu 16.10 and need to compile a file, but while compiling it make an errors like this:

```
/home/lenovo/JADE-v2.0/common/gzstream/gzstream.C:107: undefined reference to 'gzwrite'
```

I tried to install the `gzlib` with:

```
sudo apt-get install gzlib
```

but it didn't work. and shows an error.

```
E: Unable to locate package gzlib
```

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: Trying to compile how, exactly? are you linking zlib (`-lz`)? is package `zlib1g-dev` installed?

Comment: Just with command " make" . No ,how should i do this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`